# How does the browser know where to find socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

How does the browser know how to grab socket.io from that reference? The last time I checked, I didn't have a socket.io.js file in my public folder.

**Update:** Socket.io is working just fine, I'm just curious how it uses this mysterious route to get the client side socket.io code.

Thanks for the extensive answer : )

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `//socket.io/...`

Comment: Yeup. I have it with one leading slash, and it works. Just can't for the life of me figure out how the browser is actually getting that file.

Comment: I think it is being served over websockets by socket.io itself.

Comment: @Costa Resources like this are HTTP and have nothing to do with Websockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is some slight magic here.  When you install the server-side `socket.io` library and initialize it by passing it your web server, it automatically installs a route handler into your web server for any request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and it will serve a `socket.io.js` file that is designed for the client from deep within the server-side socket.io installation directory whenever that particular `/socket.io/socket.io.js` route is requested.

So, the file does not actually come from the exact path that is requested (that is just the route that a handler is installed for).  The file actually comes from the server-side installation directory (inside of `node_modules/socket.io`).  The advantage of doing it this way is that since the server side implementation of socket.io and the client-side implementation are all coming from the exact same NPM installation, they are always guarenteed to be the same version so you never have an issue with client and server versions being out of sync.

For reference, here's the relevant part of the [socket.io server code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L275) that serves `/socket.io/socket.io.js`:

```
var clientSource = read(require.resolve('socket.io-client/socket.io.js'), 'utf-8');

Server.prototype.serve = function(req, res){
  var etag = req.headers['if-none-match'];
  if (etag) {
    if (clientVersion == etag) {
      debug('serve client 304');
      res.writeHead(304);
      res.end();
      return;
    }
  }

  debug('serve client source');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
  res.setHeader('ETag', clientVersion);
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(clientSource);
};

/**
 * Attaches the static file serving.
 *
 * @param {Function|http.Server} http server
 * @api private
 */

Server.prototype.attachServe = function(srv){
  debug('attaching client serving req handler');
  var url = this._path + '/socket.io.js';
  var evs = srv.listeners('request').slice(0);
  var self = this;
  srv.removeAllListeners('request');
  srv.on('request', function(req, res) {
    if (0 === req.url.indexOf(url)) {
      self.serve(req, res);
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < evs.length; i++) {
        evs[i].call(srv, req, res);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: That's only if you're hosting the Socket.IO server on the same place as your web application, and there's absolutely no indication in the question that this is happening... and in fact in my experience, that's rare and poor practice.  There is no reason to load down your Socket.IO server with serving static files.  Host those elsewhere, and then reference the client with a full URL to the Socket.IO server.

Comment: @Brad - I disagree.  First off socket.io IS a web application.  Every socket.io connection starts with an HTTP request so EVERY socket.io server uses a web server and in a node.js world, it is very often the same http server that everything else is served from.  And further, `"/socket.io/socket.io.js"` IS the default path that socket.io hosts its own copy of the client-based socket.io.js at.  And, the OP states that it appears to be working, but they didn't do anything to make it work.  So, they're wondering how/why it works.  The socket.io server IS making it work.  What else could it be?

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of how Socket.IO works.  Nothing in his question indicated that it was actually working, so I had assumed it wasn't working because he neglected to put the full URL in for the client on his Socket.IO server.  I also had assumed he wasn't hosting his HTML on his Socket.IO server because he didn't indicate this in the question, and this isn't a common thing (nor should it be... it's a bad practice).  In any case, I think you're right about what the problem is here, so nice work on figuring out the details on a vague question.  :-)

Comment: @Brad - not sure where you got it in your head that is was a "bad practice" to use the same web server for your app as for socket.io.  That is a very, very common implementation if you start with node.js as your core back-end development environment and has all sorts of advantages.

Comment: For development, sure, do whatever is convenient.  And, if you have almost no load, that's fine too.  But if you have a ton of traffic, let the native performance of a real web server like Nginx, or something distributed like a CDN, handle all of your static HTML.  There's no reason to put load on your Socket.IO server doing just static serving which can be handled much more efficiently somewhere else.

Comment: @Brad - I'll agree that if you're going high scale, you look to offload static files from your app server.  I didn't see how this question was about that type of question.

Comment: Thanks for the full debate, this is actually opening up lots of new thoughts for me : ) Sorry if the question was vague. I truly was just curious about that mysterious route. Thanks so much!